# C# Tasks without threading and synchronization

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, task-parallel-library

I would like limit my application's Tasks and events to a single thread to avoid thread synchronization. How would I do that and what possible issues could I face by doing so?

I am making a C# IO bound application that uses events and TPL's Tasks. As a thought experiment more than anything, I am wondering if it would be possible to avoid synchronization primitives like locks and semaphores altogether by simply using a single thread for all my Tasks. In the end, I would like something like Node.js where user's code runs on a single thread and thus user does not need to worry about synchronization.

However I realize that this model is not native to .NET and that there might be many pitfalls, I assume especially around third party code and events.

My first thought would be limit the thread pool to a single thread, however I worry that this would break some native or third party functionality.

Comment: You can create your own TaskScheduler.

Comment: It depends how you implement your code but if you don't do parallel execution and you only do IO bound work and you don't ConfigureAwait(false) you should only ever touch one thread. https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html